Calculate $\angle x$ in the triangle below if AB=BC and BD=DC .
Calculate $x^o$ if $AB=BC$ and $BD = DC$
.
(*If necessary, it is possible to use approximate right triangles.)
(Answer:$30^o$)

$\angle DBC  \cong \angle DCB= 15^o  $
$ \therefore \angle CDB = 180^o -30^o = 150^o $
$ \angle ABD = 90^o - 15^o = 75^o $
$ \therefore \angle x = 180^o - 75^o - \angle BDA = 105^i - \angle BDA$
$ \angle x + \angle CAD+ \angle DCA +15^o = 90^o \implies \angle x + \angle CAD + \angle DCA = 75^o $
$ \angle BDA + \angle CDA = 360^o -150^o = 210^o $

This question is missing context, but also: try to write sentences! Concise notation is helpful for your own work, but when writing things other people will read it is best to use words and sentences, etc.

The question is an exact copy of the book.....I do not make any type of change in the text or notation precisely so that there is no misinterpretation of what the author asks and for me it is very clear what the question asks and the necessary data was all provided,

Which book? And which bits are copied form the book?

@user1729   Triangulos - Luis Ubaldo Caballero


Construct equilateral triangle $ABE$, and connected $DE$ and $EC$.
$AB=BC=BE$, so $\angle EBD= 90^o-15^o-60^o=15^o$ , $\angle BEC=(180^o-30^o)\div2= 75^o$, $\angle BED=\angle BCD= 15^o$
As $\angle DEC=\angle DCE=60^o $
So triangle EDC is an equilateral triangle.
So $BD=DC=DE$
Prove that triangle ABD and triangle AED are congruent by using SSS or SAS after getting $AB=AE, BD=DE,$ and common line $AD$, also $\angle ABD= \angle AED=75^o$ ).
$\angle BAD=\angle DAE= 60^o \div 2= 30^o $

Why $ ∠BED=∠BCD$?

To understand this: First BD is the perpendicular bisector line for EC in triangle BEC. From here, we actually can conclude that $\angle BED=\angle BCD$. If you don’t understand, just prove that triangle BED is congruent to triangle BCD (SAS) as $BE=BC$, a common line BD, and $\angle EBD=\angle CBD$.  After proving these two triangles are congruent, we can immediately said that $\angle BED=\angle BCD$.

I also use this similar method below.

The correct one is $\angle BEC =75^o$ and not $\angle AEC4

@petaarantes Fix it.

Another solution:

Let’s do the perpendicular bisector line for AC from point B. (But we don’t need really draw the line until meeting line AC.) Extend CD until meet the perpendicular bisector line at point E. Connect line $AE$.
As EA=EC, so
$\angle EAC=\angle ECA=45^o-15^o=30^o.$
$\angle AEC=180^o-30^o\times2=120^o$.
As EA=EC, so
$\angle BAE=\angle BCE=15^o$.
$\angle BEA=180^o-(15^o+45^o)=120^o =\angle AEC$
We can also find $BE=ED$ as $\angle EDB= \angle EBD=30^o$
Prove that triangle ABE is congruent to triangle ADE by SAS.
$\angle x= 15^o \times 2=30^o$.
